# adding stars to boxplots with ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have the following code,

```
 set.seed(15)
xdf <- data.frame(
  values = c(
rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = .4),
rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0.3, sd = .7),
rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0.6, sd = .15),
rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0.2, sd = .4),
rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0.4, sd = .4),
rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0.7, sd = .5)
),
groups = rep(LETTERS[1:6],each=20)
)



library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(xdf, aes(x=groups, y=values, fill=groups)) +
geom_boxplot() +
scale_fill_manual(values=pals::brewer.greens(6)) +
theme_pubclean() +
theme(legend.position = 'none') +
xlab("") +
ylab("Values") +  
stat_compare_means(ref.group="A", 
                 method = "t.test", 
                 label.y = maxvals+0.1,
                 symnum.args = list(cutpoints = c(0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1),  
                 symbols = c("****", "***", "**", "*", "ns"))
```

which produces the following plot:

[image]

If I were to remove the `ref.group="A"` argument and replace with a list of `comparisons=` then the `synum.args=` works and instead of getting `T-test, p=0.0016` etc. it replaces the p-values with asterisks. However, when using the reference group, I can't seem to get  the asterisks to replace p-values as I supposed `synum.args=` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use `after_stat` to use your symbols for the labels which are stored in computed variable `p.signif`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(xdf, aes(x = groups, y = values, fill = groups)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens") +
  theme_pubclean() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Values") +
  stat_compare_means(
    aes(label = after_stat(paste0("T-test, ", p.signif))),
    ref.group = "A",
    method = "t.test",
    symnum.args = list(
      cutpoints = c(0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1),
      symbols = c("****", "***", "**", "*", "ns")
    )
  )
```

[image]